# Find an executable file in a directory and assign it to a variable through bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am writing a few bash scripts and need some assistance with being able to find an executable file within a directory and assigning it to a variable.

so I know if I run:

```
ls -dF `find . -maxdepth 1 \( -perm -1 -o \( -perm -10 -o -perm -100 \) \) -print`
```

it will return something like this:

```
./ravend
./raven-cli
```

What I would like to do is have it return:

```
ravend
raven-cli
```

and then have something like:

coind='ravend'
coincli='raven-cli'

I am assuming I would have to do something like this code example, but i just don't know how to write it

```
output=$(ps -ef | awk '/siebsvc –s siebsrvr/ && !/awk/ { a++ } END { print a }'); echo $output
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say doing something generic to get multiple results, and then using parts of that result to specific things is not a good idea. I would suggest doing a more targetd search for each of the variables.

Disregarding this, I had fun coming up with the following solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main() {
    local coind coincli
    read -a executables -r < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -perm -1 -o \( -perm -10 -o -perm -100 \) \) -printf "%f ")

    (( "${#executables[@]}" > 2 )) && { echo "Found more than 2 executables: ${executables[*]}"; return 1; }

    local word
    word="$(comm -12 --nocheck-order <(grep -o . <<<"${executables[0]}") <(grep -o . <<<"${executables[1]}") | awk '{printf $0}')"

    for executable in "${executables[@]}"; do
        local variable="${executable/${word}/coin}"
        variable="${variable//[^a-z]/}"
        declare "${variable}=${executable}"
    done

    echo "coind: ${coind}"
    echo "coincli: ${coincli}"
}

main "$@"
exit $?
```

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -perm -1 -o \( -perm -10 -o -perm -100 \) \) -printf "%f "` - find files with executable permission in current directory, and only print file name (no path)

`comm -12 --nocheck-order <(grep -o . <<<"${executables[0]}") <(grep -o . <<<"${executables[1]}")` - find the word/characters that exist in both executable names

`grep -o . <<<"${executables[0]}"` - split string into 1 character per line (done for both executables)

`| awk '{printf $0}')` - each character is printed on a new line, this is used to collapse it into a word

`variable="${executable/${word}/coin}"` - replace (once) the common word with `coin` (will be used to set the variables later)

`variable="${variable//[^a-z]/}"` - remove all characters that isn't anything of `a` through `z` (in this case, remove `-` from the variable name

`declare "${variable}=${executable}"` - dynamically declare variable and set it's value.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. I ran a couple of tests and this is getting me where I want to be. Question though, there will not always be a -cli executable file though. When I ran this with both files in the directory it worked flawless. When I ran it with the -cli file removed it returned nothing for both variables.